Using nix-shell to build SHADERed with pkg-config
I'm attempting to build SHADERed and using nix-shell to setup an environment to build it.
My shell.nix is as follows:
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } }:

pkgs.mkShell {
  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [
    cmake
    pkg-config
  ];
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    SDL2
    glew
    glm
    python3
    sfml
  ];
  shellHook = ''
  export PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE="${pkgs.pkg-config}/bin/pkg-config"
  '';
}

Running cmake . then results in Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
and running echo $PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE gives me /nix/store/a3752l19hc76dmzh1wgrxbsxh6lfx67z-pkg-config-wrapper-0.29.2/bin/pkg-config
I've seen that adding pkg-config to nativeBuildInputs should also automatically configure PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE, but adding or removing shellHook from my shell.nix doesn't seem to make any difference.
What am I missing?

I don't have this error when using your shell in the master branch of SHADERed. I get a compilation error which doesn't seem related to a dependency/environment issue. Also SHADERed is already packaged in nixpkgs and is flagged as "broken".
